# "Disguising" the player as a mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway I could "disguise" the player as a mob? I've seen the sethbling videos of his 'goat simulator in minecraft' game, but I'm pretty sure that was done with bukkit plugins. Is there anyway I can achieve this in vanilla minecraft? I already know that I should have a command block with this effect in it to start off, to make the player invisible, but I don't know where to continue..

```
//Have a constant redstone loop going for this command block
/effect @a 14 240 372000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a link to a video demonstrating and giving a tutorial of this: [Minecraft: Disguise as a Mob in Vanilla](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD97vthq5uU)

This method seems to work fairly well judging by the video. Keep in mind, knowledge of command blocks is definitely recommended as they can injure your world if not used correctly.

Comment: Don't worry, I program for a living, so commands probable won't corrupt my world.

Comment: Alright then, good to know. :)

Comment: Also, sorry that I forgot to accept your answer, was extremely tired and went to bed. Accepted now though! :)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the video worked instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 20 hearts clock that is playing this command over and over again
`/execute @e[type=Sheep,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /tp @p ~ ~0.3 ~`
Then find a way to turn the block in front of the player into FallingSand
With the blocks Id and a frontward and upward direction and do that
Depending on what direction the player is facing

Answer (score 0):

This video has a world download link. In the world there are command blocks. You can change the mob using the names from summon commands.